# Segue from UIViewController to UITableViewController has no effect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

The issue I am having is in this particular part of the storyboard. When the table view loads it is populated correctly and everything works fine, then one of the cells can be selected and the view on the right loads up with everything fine(push). However, when selecting 'Back to News' nothing happens(push). If I press the button (nothing happens) and then select one of the other items housed in the tab bar and then select the news tab again the app has returned to the table view and all is well.

The layout can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3gsW.jpg

I am not sure what code is needed but can post whatever is requested.

My question is this, what is wrong with segue between the 'Back to News' button and the UITableViewController?

Apologies for any mistakes made, it is my first post.

Comment: you must have `navigationController as rootviewController`. do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont want to push to the tableview controller again from the news detail view controller.
There will be a back button by default since it is in navigation controller.

Comment: I set the 'Show Navigation Bar' check box, got rid of the other stuff I had added. However, now the button press yields a black screen with another back button that when pressed crashes the app. Any ideas? Any code that needs to be posted?

Comment: Nope, I figured it out. I missed something in the logs:
"nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted."

I had the segue setup from the custom cell rather than the view controller so when it was called programmatically it seemed to be called twice. @Johnykutty I will mark as accepted as you put me on the right path, greatly appreciated mate.